# WPF TabControl adding rectangles inside tab items

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a  data table containing floor/storie/level information- using this information (I add tab items to tab contol)  The number of levels are not predetermined, this is determined by the user. There is also another table for the room information, this table contains flood ID which is connected to the 'floors' data ID. I want to create rectangles for the rooms and  place these rectanges where the rooms/floors are.  I would appreciate any feedback on how to execute this opperation.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the rooms in a `Dictionary<int, List<Room>>` using the floor data ID as the index. The int would be the ID of your floor (assuming it is a number), and the List would be the list of rooms on that floor.

If this answer is headed in the wrong direction, perhaps you can post some sample code.